# Java and avoid if statements for objects with similar methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 2 classes e.g. A and B.
These classes have a couple of getter/setter methods with the same name.

Now in the code I do the following:

```
if(obj.getClassName().equals(A.class.getName())){
   A a = (A) obj;
   String result = a.getInfo();
}
else if(obj.getClassName().equals(B.class.getName())){
   B a = (B) obj;
   String result = a.getInfo();
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to call the `getInfo` avoiding the if statements.
**Note:** I can not refactor the classes to use inheritence or something else.
I was just interested if there is a trick in java to avoid the if statements.

Comment: Yes I know `instanceof`.I was wondering if I could avoid trying to detect the class altogether

Comment: The `obj` is send as part of method params from a remote call as generic objects

Comment: @Luchian:Could be either `A` or `B` or `null` or `neither`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `Object` type since there is no super common class.

Comment: @user384706: Generic object? type???

Comment: The method specifies `Object`.I cast it to specific

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817385/java-and-avoid-if-statements-for-objects-with-similar-methods/7817535#7817535

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you want to use reflection, no. Java treats two types which *happen* to declare the same method (`getInfo()`) as entirely separate, with entirely separate methods.

If you've got commonality, you should be using a common superclass or a common interface that both of them inherit. You've tagged the question "design-patterns" - the pattern is to use the tools that the language provides to show commonality.

As Eng.Fouad shows, using `instanceof` is simpler anyway - and better, as it means your code will still work with subclasses of `A` or `B`.

You can *isolate* this ugliness, of course, by putting it in a single place - either with a facade class which can be constructed from either an `A` or a `B`, or by having a single method which performs this check, and then calling that from multiple places.

Comment: Would you like to answer this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811687/can-an-object-be-considered-as-a-variable

People are waiting for your answer

Comment: @djaqeel: If folks are waiting for my answer on a C++ question, they'll be waiting for a long time :)

Comment: You are funny as well... But I think the question is general one, not specifically a C++ question.

Comment: @djaqeel: No, it's a terminology question, and the subtleties and nuances between different languages are significant.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use inheritance and want to avoid `if` statements (even using `instanceof`)... well... the best you can do is wrap the check, cast and call in a function to avoid code duplication... otherwise there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/). here is my complete example.

**Class A**

```
 package a;
    public class A {
        String info;
        public String getInfo() {
            System.out.println("A getInfo");
            return info;
        }
        public void setInfo(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }
    }
```

**Class B**

```
package a;
public class B {
    String info;
    public String getInfo() {
        System.out.println("B getInfo");
        return info;
    }
    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
package a;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class TestAB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a= new A();
        doSth(a);
    }
    private static void doSth(Object obj) {
        Class c = obj.getClass();
        Method m;
        try {
            m = c.getMethod("getInfo", new Class[] { });
            String result = (String) m.invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

See this line :

`Class c = obj.getClass();`

and

`m = c.getMethod("getInfo", new Class[] { });`

and

`String result = (String) m.invoke(obj);`

There is  no `if` statements

Answer (score 1):

If obj is declared as either A or B, you can use overloaded methods. (A good argument for type safety.) Here's a test that illustrates this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {

    class A {
        public String getInfo() {
            return "A";
        }
    }

    class B {
        public String getInfo() {
            return "B";
        }
    }

    public String doBarFor(A a) {
        return a.getInfo();
    }

    public String doBarFor(B b) {
        return b.getInfo();
    }

    public String doBarFor(Object obj) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoBarForA() {
        A a = new A();
        assertEquals("A", doBarFor(a));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoBarForB() {
        B b = new B();
        assertEquals("B", doBarFor(b));
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void shouldFailIfDeclaredAsObject() {
        Object a = new A();
        assertEquals("A", doBarFor(a)); // exception thrown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
String result = null;

if(obj instanceof A)
{
    result = ((A) obj).getInfo();
}
else if(obj instanceof B)
{
    result = ((B) obj).getInfo();
}
```

Comment: Yes I know instanceof.I was wondering if I could avoid trying to detect the class altogether

Comment: Beware of instanceof operator http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Answer (score 0):

Refer to : [this tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=332) if this is what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is an Object, you'll need to check. If you don't want to use an if-statement, you can try just casting and catch the exception:

```
String result = null;
try {
    result = ((A)obj).getInfo();
}
catch(ClassCastException e1) {
    try {
        result = ((B)obj).getInfo();
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e2) {
         // do something else
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do is make both classes implement an Interface then check for just that Interface, something like:

```
public interface HasInfo
{
    public String getInfo();
}
```

Then add `implements HasInfo` in the class definition for A and B. Then you can just check (or cast) to `HasInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use a dot as a scope resolution operator with static methods. Try something like this:

```
String a_info = A.getInfo();
String b_info = B.getInfo();
```

With objects, if two interfaces really have the same method with the same parameters and the same return type, why must they be treated differently? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implemeting-2-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method-is-o) for some more insight into the problem.

Good luck.